# Mocking async call in python 3.5

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-mock

How do I mock async call from one native coroutine to other one using `unittest.mock.patch`?

I currently have quite an awkward solution:

```
class CoroutineMock(MagicMock):
    def __await__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        future = Future()
        future.set_result(self)
        result = yield from future
        return result
```

Then

```
class TestCoroutines(TestCase):
    @patch('some.path', new_callable=CoroutineMock)
    def test(self, mock):
        some_action()
        mock.assert_called_with(1,2,3)
```

This works but looks ugly. Is there more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Also this mock doesn't work with asyncio.await because of asyncio.tasks.ensure_future

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The solution was actually quite simple:
I just needed to convert `__call__` method of mock into coroutine:

```
class AsyncMock(MagicMock):
    async def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(AsyncMock, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This works perfectly, when mock is called, code receives native coroutine

Example usage:

```
@mock.patch('my.path.asyncio.sleep', new_callable=AsyncMock)
def test_stuff(sleep):
    # code
```

Comment: This is nice, but it doesn't play well with autospec, which is basically mandatory when using MagicMock. Any thoughts on how to get that working? I'm not familiar enough with the internals...

Comment: It works perfectly for me. I used it like this:
```
@mock.patch(
    'my.path.asyncio.sleep',
    new_callable=AsyncMock,
)
def test_stuff(sleep):
    # code
```

Comment: This works. I initially like the other solution below by Ivan Castellanos. But the future is never executed and I tried like hell, but didn't get it to work.

Comment: This is as handy and elegant as it gets. At least for basic usage.

Comment: Note: `AsyncMock` is available in `unittest.mock` as of python 3.8, mock also automatically detects where it should be used (see [docs for examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.AsyncMock)).

Comment: if you use python version less than 3.8, you can use `pip install mock` to get AsyncMock, https://github.com/testing-cabal/mock

Comment: @tutuDajuju you should post that as an answer, along with an example. I would +1

Comment: how you write a side_effect with asyncmock ?

Answer (score 84):

Everyone's missing what's probably the simplest and clearest solution:

```
@patch('some.path')
def test(self, mock):
    f = asyncio.Future()
    f.set_result('whatever result you want')
    process_smtp_message.return_value = f
    mock.assert_called_with(1, 2, 3)
```

remember a coroutine can be thought of as just a function which is guaranteed to return a future which can, in turn be awaited.

Comment: what is process_smtp_message.return_value = f?  Also, where is the call to the function being tested?

Comment: @Skorpeo - i think he means mock.return_value = f

Comment: I definitely don't. Mock is the test fixture. process_smtp_message is whatever you're trying to mock obviously.

Comment: The solution is not compatible with Python 3.8 where is a native `AsyncMock` was introduced. So a code with the solution will fail with errors because of Future class issues. But a solution of Zozz with a simple `AsyncMock` implementation can work in Python 3.7 (for example) and Python 3.8 (if you will do conditional importing of native `AsyncMock`)

Comment: For ```python3.8``` and above I ended up using: ```patch.object(your_object, 'async_method_name', return_value=your_return_value)```

Comment: re: "... obviously." If it was obvious, multiple people wouldn't have been confused by it.

Answer (score 29):

Based on @scolvin answer I created this (imo) cleaner way:

```
def async_return(result):
    f = asyncio.Future()
    f.set_result(result)
    return f
```

That's it, just use it around whatever return you want to be async, as in

```
mock = MagicMock(return_value=async_return("Example return"))
await mock()
```

Answer (score 17):

Subclassing `MagicMock` will propagate your custom class for all the mocks generated from your coroutine mock. For instance, `AsyncMock().__str__` will also become an `AsyncMock` which is probably not what you're looking for.

Instead, you might want to define a factory that creates a `Mock` (or a `MagicMock`) with custom arguments, for instance `side_effect=coroutine(coro)`. Also, it might be a good idea to separate the coroutine function from the coroutine (as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines)).

Here is what I came up with:

```
from asyncio import coroutine

def CoroMock():
    coro = Mock(name="CoroutineResult")
    corofunc = Mock(name="CoroutineFunction", side_effect=coroutine(coro))
    corofunc.coro = coro
    return corofunc
```

An explanation of the different objects:

- `corofunc`: the coroutine function mock
- `corofunc.side_effect()`: the coroutine, generated for each call
- `corofunc.coro`: the mock used by the coroutine to get the result
- `corofunc.coro.return_value`: the value returned by the coroutine
- `corofunc.coro.side_effect`: might be used to raise an exception

Example:

```
async def coro(a, b):
    return await sleep(1, result=a+b)

def some_action(a, b):
    return get_event_loop().run_until_complete(coro(a, b))

@patch('__main__.coro', new_callable=CoroMock)
def test(corofunc):
    a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
    corofunc.coro.return_value = c
    result = some_action(a, b)
    corofunc.assert_called_with(a, b)
    assert result == c
```

Comment: this doesn't work, side_effect=coroutine(coro), coroutine is not defined

Comment: I actually like the original solution quite a bit better, as it doesn't require special rewriting of the test function. Any advantages to this approach over the one shown in the question?

Answer (score 11):

I don't know why nobody mentioned the default option available.
python provides a Async version of MagicMock.

You can read more about this here.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.AsyncMock

In case you are using patch then also you don't need to make any other change. It will automatically replace it with a async mock function if required.
Read more here
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch

Comment: Perhaps because the thread refers to Python 3.5 (and, by extension, all subsequent versions prior to 3.8, when `AsyncMock` was introduced)

Comment: Question was asked in 2015 when Python 3.5 was probably the "newest Python". Now in 2023 this isn't true and most people who get here from Google look for solution for much more fresh Python. So this answer is really good for today.

Answer (score 7):

Another way of mocking coroutine is to make coroutine, that returns mock. This way you can mock coroutines that will be passed into `asyncio.wait` or `asyncio.wait_for`.

This makes more universal coroutines though makes setup of tests more cumbersome:

```
def make_coroutine(mock)
    async def coroutine(*args, **kwargs):
        return mock(*args, **kwargs)
    return coroutine


class Test(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.coroutine_mock = Mock()
        self.patcher = patch('some.coroutine',
                             new=make_coroutine(self.coroutine_mock))
        self.patcher.start()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.patcher.stop()
```

Answer (score 6):

One more variant of "simplest" solution to mock a async object, which is just a one liner.

In source:

```
class Yo:
    async def foo(self):
        await self.bar()
    async def bar(self):
        # Some code
```

In test:

```
from asyncio import coroutine

yo = Yo()
# Here bounded method bar is mocked and will return a customised result.
yo.bar = Mock(side_effect=coroutine(lambda:'the awaitable should return this'))
event_loop.run_until_complete(yo.foo())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `return_value` of an async method like so:

```py
mock = unittest.mock.MagicMock()
mock.your_async_method.return_value = task_from_result(your_return_value)

async def task_from_result(result):
    return result
```

The caller will have to do `await your_async_method(..)` just like as if the method wasn't mocked.

Answer (score 1):

I like this approach, which also makes AsyncMock to behave exactly like Mock:

```
class AsyncMock:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.mock = Mock(*args, **kwargs)

    async def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.mock(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.mock, item)
```

Then you can work with it in the same way like with Mock, i.e:

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_async_mock_example(monkeypatch):
    fn = AsyncMock(side_effect=ValueError)
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        await fn()
    assert fn.call_count == 1
```