# How can I mock functions that are called by async code?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.8

This test works.

```py
def test_mock_ingest():
    with mock.patch('app.ingest.ingest') as mock_ingest:
        app.ingest.ingest('test-data', {'test-key': 'test-value'})
        assert mock_ingest.call_count == 1
```

This test fails because `mock_ingest.call_count = 0`

```py
def test_mock_ingest():
    with mock.patch('app.ingest.ingest') as mock_ingest:
        call_function_that_runs_async_code()
        assert mock_ingest.call_count == 1
```

`call_function_that_runs_async_code` calls the `app.ingest.ingest` function.

I know because I can see that the test data is ingested.

But for some reason, `mock_ingest.call_count` is still 0.

I think it has to do with the fact that the code that runs `app.ingest.ingest` is async.

**Edit:**

I'm using python 3.8.

I also tried this without success:

````
```python
def test_mock_ingest():
    with mock.patch('app.ingest.ingest', new_callable=mock.AsyncMock) as mock_ingest:
        call_function_that_runs_async_code()
        assert mock_ingest.call_count == 1
````

Comment: Did you try the following?
`def test_mock_ingest():
    with patch.object(app.ingest, 'ingest') as mock_ingest:
        call_function_that_runs_async_code()
        mock_ingest.assert_called_once()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mocking async call in python 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32480108/mocking-async-call-in-python-3-5)

Comment: @DolevP Yes but I read somewhere there are gotchas with that method so I'm relying on `call_count` instead.

Comment: @code11 I tried `new_callable=mock.AsyncMock` in python 3.8 also.  Will add that to my question.

Comment: I see. My point wasn't just using `assert_called_once()` instead of `call_count`, but rather using `patch.object` instead of `patch`.

Comment: @DolevP. Thanks, I did try that as well.  I ended up figuring it out.  It was a name reference issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution had nothing to do with async code after all.

`call_function_that_runs_async_code` wasn't calling `app.ingest.ingest`.

It was calling `ingest` after `ingest` was imported like this: `from app.ingest import ingest`.

That import is correct but due to namespace issues with mocking, importing the function in different ways across application code and test code does not work.

TIL that you patch functions where you import them, not where they are defined.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch

The correct solution code in my example should look like this:

```py
def test_mock_ingest():
    with mock.patch('async_codebase.ingest') as mock_ingest:
        call_function_that_runs_async_code()
        assert mock_ingest.call_count == 1
```

where `async_codebase` includes the import:

```py
from app.ingest import ingest
```