# How can I test async code in with two asyn with sentences?

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing

Im having a headache trying to test this code

```
 pool = await session_pool()
 async with pool.acquire() as conn:
       async with conn.cursor() as cursor:
                res = await cursor.execute(sql)

                rows = res.fetchall()

                return rows
```

I only need to patch the functions session_pool, acquire, cursor and execute, and force the return of fetchall to verify the function. Thanks!

This is the test that i build

```
class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_funtion(self):
        with patch('some_direction.session_pool') as mock_pool:
            result = asyncio.run(ClosingFunds.find(some_values))
```

And the output says

```
>               res = await cursor.execute(sql)
E               TypeError: object MagicMock can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32480108/mocking-async-call-in-python-3-5 ?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't specify the version of Python that im working on. Im working on Python 3.8. I already read that question, but was for Python 3.5